# Passing Variables by Value

Tags: python, reference, variable-assignment, key-value

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [{"id":2, "date": "2018-07-12"}]
```

Now I want to generate some nice output and have a function for it:

```
def generateOutput(myList):  
   outputList = []        
   for l in myList:            
      l['date_short'] = "Jul-12"
   outputList.append(l)

   return outputList
```

And here's where the desaster starts:

```
output = generateOutput(list)
```

output is fine but list that I need for further calculation and shouldn't have the date_short at all got a new key and is:

```
list = [ {"id":2, "date": "2018-07-12", "date_short": "Jul-12" }]
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: Make a copy of the list?

Comment: I don't understand. If the output is fine, what's the problem? If you don't want the output to have a date_short key, why are you doing `l['date_short'] = "Jul-12"`? Can you provide an example of how your desired output differs from your actual output?

Comment: You can pass a copy of the list instead: output = generateOutput(list[:])

Comment: > What's the problem?
This is only for demonstration. I need a list with the original data that stays in the core module and one I send to the output app.

Comment: > you can pass a copy of the list instead: output = generateOutput(list[:]) 

Nope. Careful, does not working. Slicing seems not work in that context (list of dictionary).
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying the dictionaries in `myList` in-place. Instead, you probably want to copy them individually before adding new values to them. Try this:

```
def generateOutput(myList):
    outputList = []
    for l in myList:
        output = l.copy()
        output['date_short'] = "Jul-12"
        outputList.append(output)
    return outputList
```

Also, you should avoid naming a variable `list` since `list` is the name of a predefined type in Python.

Comment: Does the job, thanks. "list": thanks for the good hint (only used it for here not in the original code)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a copy of the variable to the function by using the `copy` module.

```
import copy

list = [{"id":2, "date": "2018-07-12"}] 

def generateOutput(myList):  
   outputList = []        
   for l in myList:            
      l['date_short'] = "Jul-12"
   outputList.append(l)

   return outputList

generateOutput(copy.copy(list))
```